# Correct use of dplyr functions to compute per-product sales in sliding-window, without needing extra pass or join?

Tags: r, dplyr, sliding-window, split-apply-combine

Given a data frame defined by:

```
set.seed(1)
date <- sample(seq(as.Date('2016/01/01'), as.Date('2016/12/31'), by="day"), 12)
vals <- data.frame(x = rep(1:3, 4), date = date, cost = rnorm(12, 100))
vals
#    x       date      cost
# 1  1 2016-04-07 100.48743
# 2  2 2016-05-15 100.73832
# 3  3 2016-07-27 100.57578
# 4  1 2016-11-25  99.69461
# 5  2 2016-03-14 101.51178
# 6  3 2016-11-20 100.38984
# 7  1 2016-12-06  99.37876
# 8  2 2016-08-25  97.78530
# 9  3 2016-08-13 101.12493
# 10 1 2016-01-23  99.95507
# 11 2 2016-12-27  99.98381
# 12 3 2016-03-03 100.94384
```

I want to add a new column where the new value for the i<sup>th</sup> row is the sum of all the cost values for which:

- the date is less than or equal to the i<sup>th</sup> date and greater than the i<sup>th</sup> date minus 90 days
- and the x value equals the x value of row i. (In this example the combinations of x and date are unique, but in general they may not be.)

I can do this in two different ways:

```
tmp <- vals %>% group_by(date, x) %>% 
summarise(total = sum(vals$cost[vals$date <= date[1] & vals$date > (date[1] - 90) & vals$x == x[1]]))
vals %>% left_join(tmp)
```

and

```
vals %>% rowwise() %>% 
mutate(total = sum(vals$cost[vals$date <= date[1] & vals$date > (date[1] - 90) & vals$x == x]))
```

Both are pretty slow on my larger data, presumably because of all the subsetting. And I am passing the data frame back into the calculation which feels like a bit of a hack to me.

Is there a way to do this "properly" within `dplyr`?
By which I mean, without having to pass in the data frame and do slow subsetting.

Or if not, is there at least a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, (when ordered by date) you always calculate `sum(cost[index_start : index_end])` where `index_start` and `index_end` slide over the rows. This can be done more efficiently using the cumulative sum of the cost: `sum(cost[index_start : index_end]) = cumsum(cost[index_end]) - cumsum(cost[index_start - 1])`. For your data frame the code one possible implementation is the following.

```
# arrange by date so all relevant cost come after each other
vals <- arrange(vals, x, date)
group_by(vals, x) %>% 
  mutate(
    cumsum_cost = cumsum(cost),
    index_start = map_dbl(
      date,
      function(cur_date, date) {
        min(which(cur_date - days(90) <= date))
      },
      date = date),
    cumsum_cost_90_days_ago = map_dbl(
      index_start,
      function(index_start, cumsum_cost) {
        if (index_start - 1 <= 0) {
          return(0)
        } else {
          cumsum_cost[index_start - 1]
        }
      },
      cumsum_cost = cumsum_cost),
    cost_90_days = cumsum_cost - cumsum_cost_90_days_ago
  )
```

One could speed this up further if one would be smarter about getting `index_start` (for example by using the knowledge that the data frame is ordered by `date`). One easy way for the indices would be rolling joins e.g. in `data.table`.

Comment: Thanks! It seems the only easy way is to order by date first then. I was hoping to not have to do that, but that would then make it much harder I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Like `vals %>% arrange(x, date) %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(new = cumsum(cost))` ?

To solve the multi records per day issue. I guess you have to do a per-day calculation first?

```
vals %>% 
  arrange(x, date) %>%
  group_by(x, date) %>%
    mutate(cost = cumsum(cost)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
    mutate(new = cumsum(cost))
```

Comment: If it's supposed to sum multiple values for one day, this approach will run into problems.

Comment: @alistaire true. I can imagine purrr can work here better

Comment: Yes it does need to sum multiple on each day. And sorry to be annoying, I think I simplified my problem too much for the example. In my real problem I also have a condition where the date must be within the last, say 3 months so `cumsum` would no longer work. I didn't think it was so important, but I'll edit the question to add this. Sorry!

Comment: I don't see that we lose anything with a pass which precomputes the sales per-product, per-date. To handle multiple sales.

Comment: @smci Thanks. What about my update where I only want to include sales within the last 90 days? I don't see a way to tweak this to include this extra condition?